# Delete an item from a python dictionary when two keys have the same value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a python dictionary which has two keys with the same value.

```
mydict = {'a':'hi','b':'bye','c':'hi'}
```

What do I do if I want to delete just the element `'c':'hi'`

I tried both `del mydict['c']` and `mydict.pop('c',None)`. Both these give me a `KeyError`.

Comment: If you're getting a `KeyError`, then your dictionary *doesn't* contain the key `'c'`...

Comment: It has the key, I have an if statement that checks if the key is present and then it deletes it. My error looks like this: KeyError : 'hi'

Comment: **Edit the question** to provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You appear to be trying to delete based on the *value*, not the *key*, which is doomed to failure.

Comment: Post the full code and full error. Like jonrsharpe said, once you delete `'c':'hi'` you can't call it.

Comment: Post some code. Its hard to debug something that lives only in one's imagination.

Comment: It'd be interesting to see code where ``dict.pop(key, default)`` raises a ``KeyError``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there won't be a difference when you assign the same value to multiple keys. All elements in a python dict are required to have unique, immutable keys but there is no such constraint on the value. So don't worry too much about that!

This aside, both of the options you proposed behave as intended. The KeyError being thrown means that the key 'c' is not present in the dictionary. This leads me to believe that what you have shown is not in the dictionary at the time when the del or pop is called.

Comment: Yep you're right. It doesn't matter if two keys have the same value. You can still delete the key. Turns out, I was deleting the same key twice and hence the error.